# How can I use Mechanize to scrape an HP Printer Status page?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize

The status page looks like this:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportDocument/c00002742/c00004781.gif

You see the text underneath the Device Status title? That's what I want to scrape.

When navigated to, the status page is updated. I've pulled this from the page source:

```
<form id="deviceStatusPage"   method="post" action="this.LCDispatcher?nav=hp.DeviceStatus">
```

I can't seem to understand what it's actually DOING so it's hard to work out a good scraping strategy. I'm fairly sure the solution will be trivial but I can't seem to get started at all.

Should have said I've been playing with Mechanize and Beautiful Soup. The former seems like it'd achieve what I'd want, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Use a scraping library. [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a great one. `mechanize` and `BeautifulSoup` together makes very useful scrapers.

Comment: It's WHAT to use within Mechanize is the problem.

Comment: [http://stockrt.github.com/p/handling-html-forms-with-python-mechanize-and-BeautifulSoup/] is a good example for using them together.